# How should I interpret this sentence?

Tags: grammar

For context: the girl is in love with her master, and she is recounting all the times he went out of his way to save her. In the end, however, she just comes to this conclusion:

> 師匠にとっては私はただ弟子で、**助けてもらって、助けたっていうだけ**

I can vaguely understand what the latter half means, however I am still left feeling a bit unsatisfied. As in, if someone were to ask me to translate it, that part may end up losing all of the original bit of nuance. I don't really get why 助けもらって and 助けた are used in succession here, like, in which way do they compliment each other? How should this part be best translated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure of the context, but 助けてもらう means *(the subj.) is helped (received help)* and 助けた means *(the subj.) helped*.  Thus, by the sentence itself, it says *we helped each other, that's all*.